# Load lightbox on page load

Tags: jquery, lightbox

When this link is clicked, it will display the ligtbox window

```
<li><a href="#popup2" class="lightbox">Register</a></li>
```

How can I modify this so it displays automatically 2 seconds after the page has loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the seTimeout function to wait 2 seconds then run you code to do what ever you want.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    //your code
}, 2000);//2 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //lightbox function
    },2000);
});
```

It sets the time in witch your lightbox will open, with setTimeout (time is in milliseconds).

Comment: I don't know what the code would be to open it on load. Right now it is using a click.

Comment: if you add this code to your js file, it'll run when the page is fully loaded. That's what the $(document).ready() stands for.